# In M-x Info (C-h i), tables are not correctly aligned

Tags: indentation, formatting, info

### Problem

When trying to browse documentation in <kbd>M-x info</kbd> ≡ <kbd>C-h i</kbd>, the table of contents is not correctly aligned. One would expect

```
* Introduction     This is the etc etc etc etc etc .
* Details          Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                     bla bla bla bla bla.
* More             Yada yada yada yada.
```

but gets

```
* Introduction This is the etc etc etc etc etc .
* Details Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla.
* More Yada yada yada yada.
```

### Solution

Check the value of <kbd>C-h v `font-lock-extra-managed-props`</kbd>, see [detailed answer below](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41879/2308).

Answer (score 2):

In my case the origin of the issue was the variable `font-lock-extra-managed-props`, which I had set in a fontification hack in `latex-mode-hook`

```
(push 'display font-lock-extra-managed-props)
(push 'composition font-lock-extra-managed-props)
```

The variable allows `font-lock-mode` to remove text properties before it refontifies a region; When a mode uses font-lock with non-standard text-properties – such as the `'display` property used by `prettify-symbols-mode` – this is required for cleanup.

However, additions to this list must be set *buffer-local*, as otherwise they may interfere with other modes. In my case, it broke the formatting of `info-mode`, which probably formats each buffer only once rather than on-the-fly with font-lock. In my case, this lead to the fix

```
(make-local-variable 'font-lock-extra-managed-props)
(push 'display font-lock-extra-managed-props)
(push 'composition font-lock-extra-managed-props)
```

Because the issue occurred only when opening latex files, the origin became hard to track down, as I used info mode and latex files rarely shortly after another.